# Prevent Amazon Pay Button from Opening a Popup Window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following button (or link) that I'm biding to it the Amazon Payment Event.

`<a id="AmazonPayButton"></a>`

The biding goes as follows:

```
var btn = OffAmazonPayments.Button("AmazonPayButton", "AmAzOnCoDeHerE", {
        type: "PwA", color: "LightGray",
        authorization: function () {
        loginOptions = { scope: "profile payments:widget payments:shipping_address" };
        taxes = "0";
        authRequest = amazon.Login.authorize(loginOptions, "https://SomeIpHere.com/payment.aspx?taxes=" + taxes);

    },
    onError: function (error) {
    }
});
```

Now with `jQuery` I defined the click event to do some validations.

```
$("#AmazonPayButton").click(function(e){
    if(..) {
        //Allow
    }
    else {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

I expect that in case of `else`, the popup won't open, but still it does, how can I prevent it from opening?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a guess because I've never used `OffAmazonPayments.Button`, but: If it also defines a `click` handler on the button, what you're doing won't stop that handler from running. To do that, make sure you hook up your handler with jQuery *first* (before you call `OffAmazonPayments.Button` for that link), and in your handler use `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` to stop other event handlers on the link from being called.

Here's an example — your current handler's code for "stopping" the event doesn't prevent other handlers at the same level from being run: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/jerakaje/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>stopImmediatePropagation Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foo">click me</div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      $("#foo").click(function(e) {
        display("one");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      })
      $("#foo").click(function() {
        display("two");
      })
      function display(msg) {
        $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But if we add `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`, the second handler doesn't run anymore: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/jerakaje/2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>stopImmediatePropagation Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foo">click me</div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      $("#foo").click(function(e) {
        display("one");
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
      })
      $("#foo").click(function() {
        display("two");
      })
      function display(msg) {
        $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Side note: If you `return false;` from a jQuery event handler, calling `e.preventDefault()` is redundant. jQuery sees the `false` return value and calls `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` for you (but not `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`).

Comment: I know your answer is correct 100% but I placed the biding before/after the jquery click event but still no luck `:(`

Comment: @AliBassam: :-( Well, it was a bit of a guess. Sorry it didn't turn out to be what you needed. I'll leave it for a bit so others can see it didn't work, then delete it; hopefully by then you'll have found the solution. Best,

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but as I had the same problem and came across this topic here, I figure this answer might help someone else in future.

I had the same need to do some validation and potentially prevent the Amazon Payment button from submitting and creating a popup. The solution is actually pretty simple, as it turns out. Just insert your validation code into their authorization function when constructing the button. You will of course need to deal with scope when adding your own function references in there, but I leave that exercise to you.

Given the original code snippet, here is an example:

```
var btn = OffAmazonPayments.Button("AmazonPayButton", "AmAzOnCoDeHerE", {
        type: "PwA", color: "LightGray",
        authorization: function () {
//// validation code added here
            if (!validationCheckPasses()) {  // your validation would go here
                return;  // don't allow button to submit if validation failed
            }
////
            loginOptions =
    { scope: "profile payments:widget payments:shipping_address" };
            taxes = "0";
            authRequest = amazon.Login.authorize(loginOptions, "https://SomeIpHere.com/payment.aspx?taxes=" + taxes);

        },

        onError: function (error) {
        }
    });
```